# Hazard function when variables(s) are not observed

Tags: survival, hazard

Say I have a hazard function that is related to some survival time(under right independent censoring) with a number of covariates. How do I find the hazard function if some of/all covariates are not observed? Is there a standard procedure for this?

Comment: I think you mean missing survival times, and not missing variables. A variable is not particular to a single individual but relates all individuals in terms of their survival, such as their age, sex, or smoking status. Censoring is also different than missing survival time. If my survival time is missing, you do not know when or if I died. However, if my survival time is (right) *censored*, you know there was a period of time when I was alive, after which I may have died but you know not when. These are very different concepts.

Comment: Sorry, my bad for not being more specific. My question is purely a theoretical one: Given a explicit formula of the hazard function that has variables in it, if we were to not observe a variable at all, but know the distribution of it, how does one find the hazard function?

Comment: do you now mean parameters instead of "variables"? Use maximum likelihood if you have a parametric family of hazards.

Answer (score 0):

The Kaplan Meier curve is the non-parametric maximum likelihood estimate of the survivor function under missing data. As such the KM curve is a much better descriptive statistic for survival than an estimate of the raw "hazard", and presents much of the same information. For instance, the Y axis on a survivor plot is interpreted as a percentage of participants surviving past a certain point, whereas a hazard plot has Y axis interpreted as an "instantaneous rate of failure" which is not intuitive, even though they present related information.

If you fit a parametric survival model (Weibull, Exponential, Gamma, etc), you can produce an estimate of the hazard function from the model parameters. However, if the parametric assumption fails, there may be unexpected behavior in your estimates. For instance, bathtub shaped hazards will not reveal their bathtub shape when fitting exponential or weibull models.

Lastly, you can use an inefficient (and probably biased?) non-parametric hazard estimate using a kernal density estimate for the Schoenfeld residuals of the partial likelihood estimated with a Cox model having no model terms to get a flexible estimate of the baseline hazard function.